# php - Server side marker clustering

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a map on my website that is displaying 50,000 markers. These were un readable to the user due to cluttering so I implemented a clustering solution using google's markerclusterer. This works ok but due to the amount of markers, it is incrediably slow to load.

I would like to use a server side solution in the form of php but can not find out the best way to do this. This is my current setup

External php file markers-xml.php

```
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT MarkerName, Lat, Lng FROM TableName WHERE MarkerName !=''";
$Query = mysql_query($SQL);
$NumRows = mysql_num_rows($Query);
?>
<markers>
<?php       
for($i = 0; $i < $NumRows; $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query);
    $Lat = $row['Lat'];
    $Lng = $row['Lng'];
    $MarkerName = $row['MarkerName'];

    echo "<marker Lat='$Lat' Lng='$Lng' MarkerName='$MarkerName'> </marker>\n";
}
?>
</markers>
```

Main file conataining map

```
function initialize(mapvars) {
        var xmldata = "markers-xml.php";

        downloadUrl(xmldata, function(doc) {
            var xml = xmlParse(doc);
            var markersInfo = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var markers = []; 
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markersInfo.length; i++) {
                var Lat = parseFloat(markersInfo[i].getAttribute("Lat"));
                var Lng = parseFloat(markersInfo[i].getAttribute("Lng"));
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng);
                var MarkerName = markersInfo[i].getAttribute("MarkerName");  

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map,
                    title: MarkerName,
                    MarkerName: MarkerName
                });

            markers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(point);
        }

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
```

Comment: Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I currently have to use `mysql` for this, but will move to PDO soon

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a serverside solution will improve the performance. It would be possible to request filtered data on every change of the viewport to reduce the number of used markers, but you will always have do request new data what will take some time.

I think the best solution would be to use a FusionTableLayer, it will  work without problems for up to 100000 markers.

---

possible approach(Related to the comments):

when the viewport of the map changes, send the bounds of the viewport and the zoom-level to the server.

The database-query should

1. filter the results based on the given bounds
2. round the lat and lng (the accuracy of the rounding must be related to the zoom-level)
3. Group the results by the rounded latlngs
4. return the rounded latLng and the count of items for this latlng

send these data back to the client and create the markers(you may use a serverside solution to dynamically create the marker-images or use a custom overlay)

Comment: Here is an example of server side clustering http://jory.dk/AreaGMC/MapClustering.html It has 150,000+ markers and loads instantly. The only problem is that is is written in `c#` and I only know `php`

Comment: sorry, I was thinking in the wrong direction(still returning single markers but filtered by the viewport). This shouldn't be hard to achieve, I've updated my answer

Comment: You're approach makes logical sense i'm not quite sure how it translates into php though. The day my php skills advance further can't come soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

client side:
generate a get request and pass in the bounds of the viewport

```
getclusters.php?&lat2=62_676438&lon2=-63_2085681&lat1=10_6655205&lon1=-135_7183337
```

server side:
store your lat lon data in a table with a pk and a POINT data structure such that you can use a mysql spatial index (which uses r-trees rather than b-trees so grouping 50K points is seconds rather than minutes):

```
CREATE TABLE location (
 id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
 , p POINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)
 , SPATIAL INDEX(p)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

load from another table:

```
INSERT INTO location 
select id, PointFromWKB(Point(latitude, longitude))
from table_with_lat_long
```

load from csv:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv'
INTO TABLE location
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(id, @dummy, ..., @dummy, @latitude, @longitude)
set p = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',@latitude,' ',@longitude,')'));
```

write appropriate SQL to group by subdividing the viewport into equal smaller squares or some minimal distance between points based on viewport size.  as long as you are using the SPATIAL index it should run quick

your client side cluster marker javascript should render a marker based on count (1 for individual marker 2 or more for a cluster)